# No route matches [POST] "/jobs"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Job model that contains a Company_id as a foreign key. On the Job new page, I want to create a new job using simple form like this

```
  <%= simple_form_for (@job) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title, label: "Title of job" %>
    <%= f.submit 'Create', class: "btn btn-success" %>
  <% end %>
```

This is my nested route

```
  resources :companies do
   resources :jobs, only: [:show, :new, :create, :update, :destroy]
  end
```

In my jobs controller new and create method, I have

```
def new
 @job = Job.new
end

  def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)
    @company =  params[:company_id]
    @job.company_id = @company
      if @job.save
        redirect_to company_job_path
      else
        render :new
      end
  end
```

This is the route to the job show page

```
             company_job GET    /companies/:company_id/jobs/:id(.:format) jobs#show
```

and the job create page

```
            company_jobs POST   /companies/:company_id/jobs(.:format)     jobs#create
```

I keep getting the error below when I try to create a job using simple form.

No route matches [POST] "/jobs"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your nested routes you need to set `company` before jobs
so either use `before action set company`  of find company before use this

in controller

```
before_action :set_company
def new
 #@company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
 @job = @company.jobs.new
end
private
  def set_company
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
  end
```

in view pass full url

```
   <%= simple_form_for @job, :url => company_jobs_path(@company, @job), :method => :post%>
        <%= f.input :title, label: "Title of job" %>
        <%= f.submit 'Create', class: "btn btn-success" %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: thanks, it works. I checked the database and the new job saves. when i try to redirect to the job show page, i get this error No route matches {:action=>"show", :company_id=>"13", :controller=>"jobs"}, missing required keys: [:id]. this is my redirect in the create action.                        
 if @job.save
      redirect_to company_job_path                I would like to know how I can pass the new job id to the route and redirect successfully to the job show page. Thanks for your help

Comment: @HakeemBaba `if @job.save redirect_to company_job_path(@company, @job)` , as i mentioned that your route is nested and in every routes you would need to pass to `company_id` so here you in show action in your routes need `company_id` and `id` . hope it helped you , feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you.

Comment: @HakeemBaba are you still stuck in this problem?

Comment: I just tried it out and it worked perfectly, thanks a lot. I accepted the answer. i have a low reputation score, so i cant upvote it unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Just add  `<%= simple_form_for [@company, @job] do |f| %>` instead of `<%= simple_form_for (@job) do |f| %>` I suppose you have @company set when form is rendered.

Comment: I still get the same error. I dont quite understand your last comment about having @company set when form is rendered. Can you please clarify that for me?

Comment: @HakeemBaba Suppose you are on the show page then you will have to set `@company` in the action show and check for company in the form partial

Comment: I am a newbie in rails so i still struggle a lot. This is what i have in my job show page  def show                                                                                                          
                    @job = Job.find(params[:id])                                                      
                    end.  the simple form its in the Jobs new page and should only redirect to the show page

Comment: First check it in view if it is available or not then if it is available then their might be some before_filter or before_action which is setting it. check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters for information on filters